# ZSH: how can I run Vim-style substitute command in command line?

Tags: vim, buffer, zsh

I forgot the array syntax while on Zsh-commandline:

```
$ hello=[1,2,3,4] %ERR:
```

I want to fix the problem by substitution. In Vim, I would do `:.s@,@ @g`.
So how can I edit the current line, or let call it a current buffer, by running a command on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[jkramer/sgi5k:~]# list=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
[jkramer/sgi5k:~]# !:gs/,/ /                  
list=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

See zshexpn(1) for more information of history completion/alternation.

Answer (score 3):

Only using custom zle widget, for example:

```
function _-sedsubs()
{
    emulate -LR zsh
    local SEDARG="s"
    zle -R "Substitution: $SEDARG"
    local key=""
    read -k key
    local -r start=$key
    while (( (#key)!=(##\n) &&
             (#key)!=(##\r) )) ; do
        if (( (#key)==(##^?) || (#key)==(##^h) )) ; then
            SEDARG=${SEDARG[1,-2]}
        else
            SEDARG="${SEDARG}$key"
        fi
        zle -R "Substitution: $SEDARG"
        read -k key || return 1
    done
    BUFFER="$(echo $BUFFER | sed -r -e "$SEDARG")"
}
zle -N sedsubstitute                     _-sedsubs
bindkey "\C-o:s" sedsubstitute
```

Comment: How to enable this? I also enabled `vi-mode` as plugin and `bindkey -v`, but it jumps straight to `execute: `, or does nothing if I don't enable e.g. the `vi-mode` plugin.

Comment: If I start with `zsh -f` and just paste the code (either previous version or current one, only thing changed is that I replaced `zle -R "Substitution: "` at the start with `zle -R "Substitution: $SEDARG"` after the first actual code line as otherwise it is rather confusing) into zsh it works. Though you need to type fast enough. That should be fine to be placed into a `zshrc`. And I have no idea what you mean by “jumping straight to `execute:`”, but I use my keymap based on emacs one (and `zsh -f` also uses emacs by default). Maybe you are just not fast enough to type and need to tweak timeout

Comment: Or `<C-o>` in vi bindings switches mode without waiting and you actaully need to map `:s` (without `<C-o>`) in “normal” mode instead.

Comment: By default, `:` is mapped to `execute-named-cmd` in the `vicmd` keymap. Hence, if you type `:` while in vi command mode, you’ll get the `execute:` prompt — this is probably what @AnnevanRossum meant. One can of course unbind it with `bindkey -rM vicmd ‘:’`.